# How to include only the Google PHP APIs that I need (just Google Spreadsheets)?

Tags: deployment, google-sheets, dependencies, composer-php

Summary: My simple website now successfully communicates with Google Spreadsheets, but the inconvenience of adding this Google Spreadsheets API is that **deployments of my website (via deployhq.com) now take 50 minutes** when they used to take 30 seconds!

Details:

I created a simple webpage using PHP that accepts parameters and then appends a new row of data to a Google Spreadsheet.  Getting it working felt like a miracle because [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/php) was so sparse and often outdated.

Following the example there and on [Google's Github page](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client), my `composer.json` file is:

```
{
    "require": {
        "google/apiclient": "^2.0"
    }
}
```

Can I somehow avoid requiring *all* of those Google dependencies for *all* of their PHP APIs?

I'd love not to download all of the irrelevant Google API code that has nothing to do with Google Spreadsheets.

I think the massive amount of files is what is causing my deployments to take 50 minutes instead of 30 seconds.

My super basic webpage pretty much just uses the `Google_Service_Sheets` class and related classes. I want anything extraneous.

Answer (score 1):

If you download a [release of the client library](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/releases) it will include the core library and all of its dependencies, without the auto-generated classes. Then you can then download the [Sheets API generated classes](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client-services/tree/master/src/Google/Service/Sheets) separately and add them to your project. Using composer is the preferred method, as it makes it easy to get updates later.

P.S. - There are ~4200 generated files downloaded with the library. That's not trivial, but any process that takes 50 minutes to copy those over likely has room for improvement.